# create an array of all the keys in a JSONObject Android

Tags: android

Hi im wanting to create an array of all the keys in a JSONObject. my understanding (please correct me if i'm wrong) is that i need to convert the JSONObject to a Map and then create an Array from this does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No need to convert  `JSONObject` to a Map and then create an Array of keys just use [JSONObject.names()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#names%28%29) for getting all keys in an JsonArray then convert it to Array or ArrayList. example:

```
JSONObject  json = new JSONObject("json object string");
JSONArray namearray=json.names();  //<<< get all keys in JSONArray
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();     
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray)jsonObject; 
if (jsonArray != null) { 
   int len = jsonArray.length();
   for (int i=0;i<len;i++){ 
    list.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
   } 
} 

String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```